# Could not create internal topics - Stream-thread exception

Tags: internal, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to execute a simple Wordcount stream application but I face the error "Could not create internal topics - Stream-thread exception"

I have seen a similar thread but that seems to be more of a network issue.

Here is no security enabled on the kafka broker.

Only one broker is configured and still this issue.

Can someone let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you paste the error contents? Usually this happens if the internal topic exists with bad config already like a different than expected partition number. The full error will tell us better.

Answer (score 3):

Clean your temporary kafka queues. 
Run  `--list` command on kafka to see all the queues starting with your names and ending with `-changelog` & `-repartition` and manually run delete on them. 
This one worked for me.

Also, check your settings on delete.topic.enable for actual deletion happening. It was not the default setting until 1.0.0 - see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5384

Answer (score 0):

i have connected to kafka using kafka tool and delete them manually